# Azure B2C External provider with custom claims and policies

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, policy

I have an Azure B2C tenant with some identity providers (Facebook, LinkedIn, etc) and a custom claim where the user is able to choose a gender.

During the sing up with one of those, I'm able to get the gender's claim in the token, but this doesn't happen when the user signs in. I was wondering where is the right place to map/include this custom claim since I've been using the base custom policies: [SocialAndLocalAccount](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts)

Any clue about where to get it? I have my custom claim inside the **SelfAsserted-Social's Technical Profile**  but no luck during the sign in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SelfAsserted-Social technical profile will only be executed on the first time the user connects with his social account.

As you can see [from the comments in the user journey](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L1071)

`Show self-asserted page only if the directory does not have the user account already (i.e. we do not have an objectId).`

You need to persist that claim if you want to reuse it [as per comment here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L788)

`If a claim is to be persisted in the directory after having been collected from the user, it needs to be added as a PersistedClaim in the ValidationTechnicalProfile referenced below`

You then need to read it from AD in your `AAD-UserRead...` technical profiles

And output it in your Relaying Party's output claims.

Follow this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-configure-user-input#add-a-claim-to-the-user-interface for the Social profiles where `city` in the examples is your `gender` claim.